# ASP.NET Core layout is not loaded in my area

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, layout

My layout name is = `_DefaultLayout`.

Controller:

[image]

_ViewStart:

[image]

Index.cshtml:

[image]

The CSS is not loaded in this page, but on another page it is loaded.

Please help my to fix this problem

Thanks

Comment: Hi @mahdi yadi, what is the another page? Does it outside the Area? Which `_ViewStart` did you define the Layout, the one in Area or outside the Area? Pls check the another page, if its related _ViewStart.cshtml add correct Layout. Also please share these details to us.

Comment: Please provide code as text instead of images, the way it is written right now the question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like typo problem. The suffix for layout code is predefined. Therefore, change `_DefaultLayout.csshtml` to `_DefaultLayout.cshtml`.

Then in the _ViewStart.cshtml you can write:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DefaultLayout.cshtml";
}
```

And check that `Build Action` property of the `_DefaultLayout.cshtml` file is set to `Content`.

For additional information see: [Layout in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0)